# 1984 accounting software running in VirtualBox fails to print property to an LPT passthrough, but other software seems fine

Tags: emulation, printer, troubleshooting

My family still runs their business with an accounting package from 1984.  The computer running it is old enough to drink.  I’m trying to move it to a virtual machine.  I’ve purchased a System 76 running Pop! OS tower and installed a PCIe parallel card.  In VirtualBox I’ve installed a FreeDOS guest and passed the parallel port in via

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "FreeDOS" —lpt1 "0x378" 5
```

and can print from the command prompt.

The accounting package, BPI System’s General Accounting program version C.13 can print to the screen, a file, or to the printer.  Screen and file printing work fine.  Printer printing is the problem.  It is doubling up each character.  So “McMaster Carr” prints as “MMCCMMAASSTTEERR  CCAARR” and 314.33 prints as 331144..33.  I have no idea how to troubleshoot.  During the printing session it starts with “Error!  Printer not ready!” which can be cleared by pressing the spacebar but the same error returns every couple of printed lines and can be cleared by the spacebar again.

If I print the file from the command line I do not get the double letters.

To test the setup I bought a reconditioned Okidata Microline 320 Turbo printer off ebay.  I’m using the cable that came with it.

Any ideas?  Better solutions?  I’m not against booting to DOS directly, but I kind of want the easy backup of the entire “computer” that running it as a virtual machine gives me.

Comment: I think the problem is not in the retro software if it has worked so far in the retro system. So the problem might be in the modern Linux distro, modern printer adapter, modern VM machine or modern FreeDOS. Or the second hand bought printer or cable. Test individually which is or is not the problem.

Comment: @Justme OP says printing works from the command line.  Thus, it can’t be a hardware issue.

Comment: Is McMaster Carr supposed to be bold?

Comment: What Linux printer driver are you using?

Comment: @RonJohn You cannot guarantee that there is no hardware problem in the parallel adapter, which only happens when you let a DOS program access a modern parallel port through VM directly via IO ports, instead of using VM provided printer BIOS interface through DOS which will also go through host OS printer driver.

Comment: Have you tried different emulators (QEMU, maybe DOSBox-X if it even supports passthrough)? Have you inspected parallel port traffic from the guest?

Comment: You might want to explain what a "System 76" and a "Pop! OS tower" is supposed to be. Also, does that package have a it's own printer driver? If yes, you may want to configure it to the printer used (or change that to an emulation the program knows if that' possible). To see if it just works, try using the 'dumbest' printer offered. Last there's always the way to print to file and have it printed using 'print' via a batch job.

Comment: ' “McMaster Carr” prints as “MMCCMMAASSTTEERR CCAARR” ' looks more like it's trying to print bold by adding Backspaces, and that Backspace doesn't work. 
"C<backspace>C" would print a 'C' twice on the same position, if that backspace is wrongly configured, it'll print 'CC' instead

Comment: Pop!_OS is a Linux distro based on Ubuntu.

Comment: And last but not least: does printing from a physical PC work any better?

Comment: @AlanB Nice, but better to improve the question so everyone can understand.

Comment: I can understand why it might bold `MCMASTER CARR` but not a value like `314.33`, unless it's a total of some sort. So my two questions would be (1) can you tell if the space in `MCMASTER CARR` is also doubled? (2) Are all numbers doubled (better yet, is *everything* doubled)?. The first would be useful if not doubled as it could isolate the problem to the guest rather than the infrastructure (it's possibly unlikely to bold spaces). The second would almost certainly put the problem in the guest if only some things are doubled.

Comment: Old PCs used to have a BIOS settings for LPT, maybe some initial settings needed either at bios or linux level ? Also, some printer applicational setup that was lost moving the app to a vm? About the printer not ready, is lpd installed? Lastly, VirtualBox not the best choice for virtualization, outdated,  weak and buggy. You have better alternatives both open source native to Linux and paid. There are a lot of variables on your question that have to be trimmed down.

Comment: Actually, can you create a text file containing `C<bs>C<cr><lf>` and print it using the methods that *don't* double characters? If that comes out as `CC`, you've isolated (but not yet solved) the problem.

Comment: What printer does the current old hardware use?  If not the same as the Okidata 320, there would be escape sequence problems.  Install a word processor, and see if that works.

Comment: @paxdiablo Ive encountered dot matrix printers that  in "letter quality mode" double everything, n go over 4x for bold. This is of course a feature of the driver, so doubling everything is possible

Comment: I still have a requirement to print to dot matrix from a particular application and in Windows land this always works better by setting the printer emulation, font, pitch to Epson via the printer front control panel, and then taking printer drivers out of the equation by sending data to it in RAW mode. I don't know if (presumably) CUPS has an equivalent.

Comment: @Chad, when you "print from the command line", is that the DOS command line?

Comment: Is all printed output of this software just ordinary ASCII characters, 12 per inch monospaced, 66 lines per page in default font, no bold or italics, no frames or graphics? If so, printing to a disk file and then spooling the file out via the PRINT command might be a solution. Also, it would be interesting to know more about the printer choices offered by the accounting package. In 1984 software would often support RS-232C connections, daisy-wheel printers, plotters, etc.

Comment: what happens if you print to the file lpt1 ? just a thought

Comment: Chad, there's at least four or five good suggestions/queries here so you may not get much joy until you action some of them.

Answer (score 10):

Back in the 1970s, as a college project, I wrote an emulator for a minicomputer (in Fortran (!!)). When my professor ran a program written for the minicomputer, the teletype output was doubled, character by character. It turns out that the problem was my emulator always returned Ready when the program polled the (emulated) UART transmitter (since the output was buffered by the host OS). However, in the real mini, the transmitter was never fast enough to do this and always returned Not-Ready at least once. The program was coded to assume that it would get Not-Ready at least once per transmitted character and this bug (which was hidden on the real hardware) was exposed by my emulator.

I can’t help but wonder if something similar is happening with the old accounting software. Unfortunately, assuming this is correct, I don’t have an solution for you.

Comment: I honestly can’t believe my answer has gotten so many upvotes. It’s really just an anecdote and is probably not reverent to the question.

Comment: Take the money and run!

Answer (score 9):

Back in the early 1980s, some applications would operate the printer port hardware directly, not going through DOS or BIOS.

I'm suspicious that Virtual Box is emulating the hardware, but being fooled by the way this package operates it. If it was collecting a byte each time one was written to the correct I/O port, and then doing it again when the control signals were operated, that could look like this.

I'd look *really carefully* at Virtual Box's printer port emulation controls.

Comment: It sounds possible to me that the process is trying to write directly to RAM for printing and that location is different in virtual environment

Comment: @NiklasRosencrantz Why should writing to some specific RAM address trigger printing? And why do you think will a virtual environment allow a guest access memory in the host directly?